# Firefox web browser 50.1.0 is not opening with Selenium webdriver 3.0.1 and Java 1.8

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am using Firefox browser version 50.1.0, Selenium 3.0.1, Java 1.8, TestNG and Eclipse.
I'm unable to open Firefox browser with following code:

```java
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Login {
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\JavaPrograms\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
}
}
```

But I got the following exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:50091 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
>       at test.Login.setup(Login.java:12)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:634)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
>   Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:50091 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       ... 32 more

Comment: Please, provide more information. What does it mean 'firefox is not opening'. Do you have an exeption? Maybe it opened and immidiately terminated?

Provide stacktrace information

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in your URL -
You are using

```
www.google.co.in
```

need to change -

```
http://www.google.co.in
```

As `http` and `https` required in URL

Comment: Still i am unable to open the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\JavaPrograms\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver;

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
}
}
```